# Do map series work with 3D scenes in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, global-scene, map-series, local-scene

In ArcGIS Pro 1.2, I added a map frame containing a scene to a layout and found out the "Map Series" button (in the "page setup" group on the "layout" tab) was grayed out.

Do scene/3d and map series work together? If they do, what might I have missed?

Comment: I can confirm it's not in ArcGIS Pro 1.3 too

Answer (score 1):

Esri employee Jeremy Wright confirmed on [their forum](https://geonet.esri.com/message/607149) that Map Series is not enabled for 3d in ArcGIS Pro 1.2:

> At this time, Map Series is only enabled for 2D views.  I'll let the
>   team know you're interested in using it in 3D as well .  Do you have
>   any specific examples of scenarios that would be best served by a 3D
>   map series?